# How to handle url param changes in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have initial url

```
/processes/new
```

After making changes i want to save it & navigate to

```
/processes/_generatedprocessID_
```

So i subscribe to `routerWillLeave` and hope it will fire on url param changes. But it is not happening.
Here is my router for these urls:

```
<Route path="processes/:id" component={Process} />
```

Should i create a copy of it:

```
<Route path="processes/new" component={Process} />
```

or there are some more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a container that contains those components, this routing logic could be done there.

```
function saveSomething(something){
    //some save logic that returns id
    changeRoute(returned_id)
}

function changeRoute(returned_id){
    history.pushState(null, `processes/${returned_id}`);
}
```

Note: you will need this ->

```
NameOfTheCoponent.contextTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object
};
```